# Django group by one field and get max by other

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have this model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    b_id =  models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, unique=True)
```

I use this for storing trade orders from exchange that I get from api

the usual orders I get looks like this:

```
#order1 (symbol='btc/usdt', b_id =1)
#order2 (symbol ='btc/usdt, b_id=2)
#order3 (symbol = 'eth/usdt', b_id=8)
#order4 (symbol = 'eth/usdt', b_id=9)
#b_id is unique id I get from exchange
```

To get correct history of orders I need to get order with biggest b_id grouped by symbol

so I need function that will return object something like:
`result = {'btc/usdt': 2, 'eth/usdt': 9}`

Right now I just use simple cycle:

```
symbols=['btc/usdt', 'eth/usdt','link/usdt']

for symbol in symbols:
    last_order = Order.objects.filter(symbol=symbol).latest('b_id')       
    since = last_order.b_id
    sinces[symbol]=since
```

But it queries database to often. Any ideas how to reduce database calls?

UPD: Look I have list of orders, they are grouped by symbol, for example I have five `BTC/USDT` orders and six `ETH\BTC` orders.
Each order has unique `b_id` field.

To get correct history of orders from API I need only to know the order with latest (or biggest) b_id

for example if I have two orders 'BTC\USDT`

```
order1 (symbol='btc/usdt', b_id =1)
order2 (symbol ='btc/usdt, b_id=2)
```

I need to select just one with `b_id=2` and the same with other symbols

Comment: this does not make sense to me `I need to get order with biggest b_id grouped by symbol` can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @VishalSingh see update

Answer (score 1):

cast values_list to dict as expected

```py
from django.db.models import Max
qs = Order.objects.values('symbol').annotate(max_id=Max('b_id'))\
    .values_list('symbol', 'max_id')
result = {k:v for k,v in qs}
print(result)
```

Comment: seems to be what I need, I will check this solution

Comment: result = {k:v for k,v in qs}
 - what does this mean?

Comment: It converts from queryset to list, how does this pattern called?